# Regex with several capture groups

Tags: php, regex, expression, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a working regex to extract several information. The php code is the folowing:

```
<?php

$re = "/(\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{2}).+(\\w{3}).+\\w{3}.+(\\w{2}\\s\\d{4}).+(\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\n).+(\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{2}).+(\\w{2}\\s\\d{4}).+(\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\n).+((FNC|PXO)\\d{3})/"; 
$str = "***NEUBUCHUNG ***\n 24.01.15  TXL  FNC  AB 2306  11:40   15:20\n 31.01.15  FNC  TXL  AB 2307  16:05\n FNC044  RESIDENCIAL VILA LUSITANI    9000-120 FUNCHAL\n  1  DOPPELZIMMER                     FRUEHSTUECK\n SPO1101\n INKL. REISELEITUNG UND TRANSFER AB/BIS\n FLUGHAFEN\n F368966  HERR EIDAM, KLAUS               54\n F368966  FRAU EIDAM, SONJA               54"; 

$str2 = "***ÄNDERUNG ***\nNEU:11.04.15 DUS  AB 2646  13:15   16:25\n    18.04.15 FNC  DUS  AB 2647  17:15\n   FNC027    PESTANA CARLTON MADEIRA   9004-531 FUNCHAL\n 1  DO-MEERBLICK                       F\nF365474 HERR   PETERS, HANS                                O 03.01.15\nLANGZEITERMÄSSIGUNG 10%\nSPO-JAN_SALES 20%\nFRÜHBUCHER 10%\nINKL. REISELEITUNG UND TRANSFER AB/BIS\nFLUGHAFEN\nZimmer in ruhiger Lage\n(unverbindlicher Kundenwunsch)\nNEU:\nF365474 FRAU   PETERS, ULRIKE                              O 03.01.15"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches)
?>
```

https://ideone.com/UdIaA7

Regex with str: https://regex101.com/r/rF0uP7/5

Regex with str2: https://regex101.com/r/cV6iF9/1

However it works perfectly for str it does not match in str2, and I cant find the reason why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.+(\w{3})` in the beginning must be optional. Wrap it with `(?:.+(\w{3}))?`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cV6iF9/2)

Also, you have too many `.+`, in most places, you meant to just match whitespaces, and thus are better turned into `\s+`. Also, dots that are meant to match literal dots must be escaped.

Use a more optimized:

```
(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})(?:\s+(\w{3}))?\s+\w{3}\s+(\w{2}\s\d{4}).+(\d{2}:\d{2}\n)\s+(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}).+(\w{2}\s\d{4})\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}\n).+((FNC|PXO)\d{3})
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cV6iF9/3)

Comment: Note you should not be using any modifiers with the regex pattern in PHP (maybe `/u` if you deal with UTF texts). Just `preg_match_all('~(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})(?:\s+(\w{3}))?\s+\w{3}\s+(\w{2}\s\d{4}).+(\d{2}:\d{2}\n)\s+(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}).+(\w{2}\s\d{4})\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}\n).+((FNC|PXO)\d{3})~u', $str, $matches)`.

Comment: You are a master Wiktor! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

***However it works perfectly for str it does not match in str2, and I cant find the reason why***

Here is the Culprit Expression: `(\\w{3}).+\\w{3}`

And in $str you had `24.01.15  TXL  FNC  AB`

But in $str2, you had:  `11.04.15 DUS  AB`

Your Regex could read better like so:

```
$re = "#(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})(?:\s+(\w{3}))?\s+\w{3}\s+(\w{2}\s\d{4}).+(\d{2}:\d{2}\n)\s+(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}).+(\w{2}\s\d{4})\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}\n).+((FNC|PXO)\d{3})#si";
```

[Quick-Test](https://eval.in/642901).